# Jquery FullCalendar ListWeek wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using the "ListView" view and have not set any options related to minTime or MaxTime. In the array I see the event as

```
start: 2021-06-21 00:00 
end: 2021-06-24 08:00
```

In the render it ends on June 23rd writing in the first column 00:00 - 08:00 but it should end on June 24th.

If I try to activate the "AgendaWeek" view it draws the event correctly.

This happens with hours less than 09:00. If I put 9 o'clock up it considers me on the right day. Why?

In my opinion in the "ListWeek" view even a single second should end on the correct day, or at least looking at how long the minimum duration slot is set

Comment: Are you perhaps running into problems with timezone offsets?  Where the date functions are assuming UTC -8 or something?

Comment: This appears to be a bug, which is resolved by upgrading to a newer version of fullCalendar - 3 is now quite old. No issues in the latest v5, those dates work as they should - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/poeMZmE . BTW in v3 it doesn't seem to draw it correctly in agendaWeek either - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYvqjXW (not unless there's something else about your event data which isn't reflected in the information you've provided).

Answer (score 0):

This option works with v3:

```
nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00'
```